# Client for Kafka testing

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to setup a Kafka environment. I already have implemented a Kafka producer and consumer in my code.

Is there a Kafka test client I can use to test this setup?
Basically, what I want is this:

```
my code publishes some event.
test client gets it.

my test client publishes some event.
My code gets it.
```

IS there a Kafka test client that can be used to do the above? I tried searching the Kafka website and found nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The Java API comes with MockConsumer and MockProducer for unit testing, as well as TopologyTestDriver for Kafka Streams.

If you want *integration testing* with a real broker, you can use testcontainers (i.e. Docker), or use spring-test-kafka (Spring not required)

Answer (score 0):

Cucumblan-message library contains predefined Gherkin step definition for Kafka message/event testing.

**No need to create any consumer or producer and this framework will take care.
This code base will help to test any Kafka messages.**

Refer the following code based from your sample:

https://tutorials.virtualan.io/#/Cucumblan-message

https://github.com/virtualansoftware/cucumblan/blob/master/samples/cucumblan-message-testing/src/test/resources/features/kafka.feature#L47

Need to implement simple class JSON based consumer class for read message and validate the message.

https://github.com/virtualansoftware/cucumblan/blob/master/samples/cucumblan-message-testing/src/test/java/io/virtualan/test/msgtype/impl/JSONMessage.java

```
Scenario: check produce and consume event validation 1
Given Send inline message pets for event MOCK_REQUEST on pet with type JSON
  | {   "category": {     "id": 100,     "name": "Fish-POST"   },   "id": 100,   "name": "GoldFish-POST",   "photoUrls": [     "/fish/"   ],   "status": "available",   "tags": [     {       "id": 100,       "name": "Fish-POST"     }   ] } |
And Pause message PROCESSING for process for 2000 milliseconds
When Verify-by-elements for pets for event MOCK_RESPONSE contains 101 on pet with type JSON
  | id            | i~101           |
  | category.name | german shepherd |
Then Verify for pets for event MOCK_RESPONSE contains 101 on pet with type JSON
  | id,name, category/id:name,status            |
  | i~101,Rocky,i~100:german shepherd,available |
And Verify for pets for event MOCK_RESPONSE contains 101 on pet with type JSON
  | id,name, category/id:name,tags/id:name,status,photoUrls            |
  | i~101,Rocky,i~100:german shepherd,i~101:brown\|,available,string\| |
```